# .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages website template and how to cache MSFT Graph calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, razor

I've set up a simple ASP.NET Core 2.2 website in VS2019 and have included the [Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web) project to make calls using MSAL.NET to the Microsoft Graph API.

I've been successful in making calls to the graph including showing my photo from the `/me` endpoint in the top navbar by injecting the `tokenAcquisition` and `graphApiOperations` as guided from the [sample application on docs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) as follows:

```
public async Task OnGet()
{
    var accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(HttpContext, new[] { ScopeConstants.ScopeUserRead });        
    var photo = await graphApiOperations.GetPhotoAsBase64Async(accessToken);

    ViewData["photo"] = photo;
}
```

Following along with the template site, each page references the `_layout.cshtml` file which has a reference to `_LoginPartial.cshtml` which looks like this:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/AdminSettings">
                    <img class="circle-photo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @ViewData["photo"]" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

## My ask:

I want to show the photo, and possibly other Graph data on every Razor page without manually calling the Graph on each page. Since the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is not a Razor page I can't put the results in `@ViewData` however I don't know of another way. It seems wasteful to ask the Graph to pull the `/me` data for every page; not to mention poor design.

Is there a way to cache the results and reference them across multiple pages?

Comment: Just an update, Microsoft.Identity.Web is now a NuGet package. We encourage its usage to keep your library updated and with bug fixed. [Microsoft.Identity.Web wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the <cache> taghelper in ASPNET Core, [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

I'd be tempted to go with "vary by query" and base the query in question on usertoken/cookie values, so you refresh only when the token expires.

```
<cache vary-by-query="Thing1,Thing2">
    <span>Some Stuff I need to cache</span>: @ViewData[MyStuff]
</cache>
```

I'm sure there's a variation on this that could be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't have an official Blazor sample with Microsoft.Identity.Web (which now is a nuget package).

A possible workaround is making `_host` as a Page, so the method `[AuthorizeForScopes]` can get triggered. Here is an example: https://github.com/wmgdev/BlazorGraphApi/blob/master/BlazorGraphApi/Pages/_host.cshtml.cs
Apparently this users approach worked. Then you can use `Microsoft.Identity.Web` built in token cache providers.